# Replacing a character in a string but it duplicate

Tags: python

This is a line of code I create that will replace a '_' with a character from a string

```
def test():
    time = -1
    in_time = 0
    n = 'c__rd_nate'
    new_n = ''
    word = 'coordinate'
    chr = 'i'
    for w in word:
        time = time + 1
        if w == chr:
            for i in n:
                if in_time == time:
                    u = i.replace(i, chr)
                    new_n = new_n + u
                    in_time = in_time + 1
                else:
                    in_time = in_time + 1
                    new_n = new_n + i

                if len(word) == in_time:
                        break
```

Output:

```
>>>c__rdinate
```

But when applying the same rules for the duplicate character 'o' in word

```
def test():
    time = -1
    in_time = 0
    n = 'c__rd_nate'
    new_n = ''
    word = 'coordinate'
    chr = 'o'
    for w in word:
        time = time + 1
        if w == chr:
            for i in n:
                if in_time == time:
                    u = i.replace(i, chr)
                    new_n = new_n + u
                    in_time = in_time + 1
                else:
                    in_time = in_time + 1
                    new_n = new_n + i

                if len(word) == in_time:
                        break
```

Output:

```
>>>co_rd_natec__rd_nate
```

I know what the error is but I'm stuck at creating a solution for this type of problem!

This is some more output in the same situation!

```
def test():
    time = -1
    in_time = 0
    n = 'd__r'
    new_n = ''
    word = 'door'
    chr = 'o'
    for w in word:
        time = time + 1
        if w == chr:
            for i in n:
                if in_time == time:
                    u = i.replace(i, chr)
                    new_n = new_n + u
                    in_time = in_time + 1
                else:
                    in_time = in_time + 1
                    new_n = new_n + i

                if len(word) == in_time:
                        break






    print(new_n)
test()
```

Output:

```
>>>do_rd__r
```

Comment: Show some input and expected output. "_will replace a `_` with a character from a string_" is as vague as they come.

Comment: For a string "s" to create a new string where character at position "time" is replaced by "c" simply write "s[:time] + c + s[time+1:]"

Answer (score 0):

Converting the string to a list and then performing item assingment would be much more convenient.

This is a much more simplified way of constructing the code:

```
def test():
count = 0
n = list('c__rd_nate')
word = 'coordinate'
chr = 'o'
for w in word:
    if w == chr:
        n[count] = chr
    count += 1

print(''.join(n))
```

output:

```
coord_nate
```

Edit:
If you would prefer to still keep the variable `new_n` then you can do something like this:

```
def test():
count = 0
n = list('c__rd_nate')
new_n = ''
word = 'coordinate'
chr = 'o'
for w in word:
    if w == chr:
        n[count] = chr
    new_n = new_n + n[count]
    count += 1

print(new_n)
```

output:

```
coord_nate
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't have to complicate too much. If you used indexing, problem can be solved with ease. If pattern matches, then concatenate that letter from variable "word" else concatenate from variable "n"

```
n = 'c__rd_nate'
new_n = ''
word = 'coordinate'
chr = 'o'
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] == chr:
        new_n += word[i]
    else:
        new_n += n[i]
        
print(new_n)
```

This works for both 'o' and 'i'.

Output for 'o'

```
coord_nate
```

Output for 'i'

```
c__rdinate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def test():
    n = 'doorian'
    word = 'd__r_an'
    ch = 'o'
    return ''.join(_l if _l == '_' and word_l == ch else word_l 
                   for word_l, _l in zip(word, n))
```

Or in cycle

```
def test():
    n = 'doorian'
    word = 'd__r_an'
    ch = 'o'
    res = ''
    for word_l, _l in zip(word, n):
        if _l == '_' and word_l == ch:
            res += _l
        else:
            res += word_l
    return res
```